# Is there a search engine with reverse search mechanism: processing multiple queries and retrieving a single result for each of them?

Tags: information-management, search, search-engine, text-search

Most text search engines are intended for identification of multiple depositories storing the text of a user's query. I need one that does the opposite. Imagine we have two databases with overlapping coverage and we need to know what content is represented in only one of them. One way to do it would be by creating a file with information items extracted from one of these databases and uploading this file to a search engine which returns a list of those items of the uploaded ones that were not found in another database. An implementation of this approach exists ([Batch Citation Matcher](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1629443/)), but its application is limited to the database embedding it (PubMed). Is there an analogues application which can be applied to any website?

Comment: Do I understand you correctly: You start with n keywords and get a result for reach search, then you want the overlap/intersection of the result sets?

Comment: I'm not sure that you understand me correctly, sir. Imagine you have two databases and you need to know what content is represented in only one of them. The best way to do it would be by creating a file with information items extracted from one of these databases and uploading this file to a search engine which returns a list of those items of the uploaded ones that were not found in another database.

Comment: I see you want to find out unique entries. Are we talking about (scientific) literature databases or is this more general?

Comment: Specifically, I would like to apply the application to researchgate.net which is a depository of scientific publications but not exclusively and it lacks the organization usually found in academic literature databases.